# Animating a 'Slide' iOS UIView but associated SubViews don't move

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiviewanimation

I'm having a problem with what I thought was a simple UIView slide animation from a UINavigationBar. I have a UIView with a UIButton and I would like to simulate a slide
down/up effect from the Navigation Bar by animating the View height. The problem is the View animates but any SubViews e.g. UIButton stay fixed.

I'm coding in Xamarin (C#) but I'm sure it's simple enough to read for Objective-C coders

```
if (_menuView == null)
{
   // set initial frame
   _menuView = new MenuView{Frame = Window.Frame};

   // store original "expanded" height for later
   _expandedMenuHeight = _menuView.Frame.Height;

   // set the frame to underneath the NavigationBar
   var frame = ((UINavigationController)Window.RootViewController).NavigationBar.Frame;
   var y = frame.Bottom;

   // Add to Window View
   menuView.Frame = new RectangleF(_menuView.Frame.X,y,_menuView.Frame.Width,0);
   Window.Add(_menuView);
 }

 // Toggle View Height - if collapsed, expand, if expanded, collapse
 var height = _menuView.Frame.Height == 0 ? _expandedMenuHeight : 0;

 // Animate the height
 UIView.Transition (_menuView,0.2,UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn |   UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews,() => {
 _menuView.Frame = new RectangleF(0,_menuView.Frame.Y,_menuView.Frame.Width,height); },null);
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

[image: UIView & child SubViews not animating]

Comment: You probably just need to set autoresizesSubviews on the view in question ... unfortunately I've no idea how you'd do that in Xamarin. In cocoa, its trivial: view.autoresizesSubviews = YES.

Comment: Thanks David, in the end it was the view.clipsToBounds = YES; that did the job. BTW - I also had view.autoresizesSubviews = YES in case anyone else is looking at the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not so clear with Xamarin. But in objectiveC, you could use,

```
view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

So when you are trying to reduce the height the subviews would also be hidden.

Comment: That did the job, I knew it was simple !